# work with json in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, datatypes

Is there an easy way to work with JSON within Oracle?  I have a stored procedure that I use to call web services quite often, JSON is a format that I am familiar with in web development context, but what is the best way to work with JSON within a stored procedure?  For instance take the CLOB response from the URI, convert that to a JSON object and get a value from that?

For reference sake, here is the procedure I used to fetch URLs

```
create or replace procedure macp_URL_GET(url_resp in out clob, v_url in varchar2) is
   req     Utl_Http.req;
   resp    Utl_Http.resp;
   NAME    VARCHAR2 (255);
   VALUE   VARCHAR2 (1023);
   v_msg   VARCHAR2 (80);
   v_ans clob;
--   v_url   VARCHAR2 (32767) := 'http://www.macalester.edu/';
BEGIN
   /* request that exceptions are raised for error Status Codes */
   Utl_Http.set_response_error_check (ENABLE => TRUE );
   /* allow testing for exceptions like Utl_Http.Http_Server_Error */
   Utl_Http.set_detailed_excp_support (ENABLE => TRUE );
   /*
   Utl_Http.set_proxy (
      proxy                 => 'www-proxy.us.oracle.com',
      no_proxy_domains      => 'us.oracle.com'
   );
   */
   req := Utl_Http.begin_request (url => v_url, method => 'GET');
   /*
    Alternatively use method => 'POST' and Utl_Http.Write_Text to
    build an arbitrarily long message
  */

  /*
   Utl_Http.set_authentication (
      r              => req,
      username       => 'SomeUser',
      PASSWORD       => 'SomePassword',
      scheme         => 'Basic',
      for_proxy      => FALSE      --this info is for the target Web server 
   );
   */

   Utl_Http.set_header (r => req, NAME => 'User-Agent', VALUE => 'Mozilla/4.0');
   resp := Utl_Http.get_response (r => req);
   /*
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Status code: ' || resp.status_code);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Reason phrase: ' || resp.reason_phrase);
   FOR i IN 1 .. Utl_Http.get_header_count (r => resp)
   LOOP
      Utl_Http.get_header (r => resp, n => i, NAME => NAME, VALUE => VALUE);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (NAME || ': ' || VALUE);
   END LOOP;
   */
--test
   BEGIN
      LOOP
         Utl_Http.read_text (r => resp, DATA => v_msg);
         --DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_msg);
         v_ans := v_ans || v_msg;
         url_resp := url_resp || v_msg;
      END LOOP;
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN Utl_Http.end_of_body
      THEN
         NULL;
   END;
--test
   Utl_Http.end_response (r => resp);


   --url_resp := v_ans;

EXCEPTION
   /*
    The exception handling illustrates the use of "pragma-ed" exceptions
    like Utl_Http.Http_Client_Error. In a realistic example, the program
    would use these when it coded explicit recovery actions.

    Request_Failed is raised for all exceptions after calling
    Utl_Http.Set_Detailed_Excp_Support ( ENABLE=>FALSE )
    And it is NEVER raised after calling with ENABLE=>TRUE
  */
   WHEN Utl_Http.request_failed
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Request_Failed: ' || Utl_Http.get_detailed_sqlerrm
      );
      url_resp :='Request_Failed: ' || Utl_Http.get_detailed_sqlerrm;
   /* raised by URL http://xxx.oracle.com/ */
   WHEN Utl_Http.http_server_error
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Http_Server_Error: ' || Utl_Http.get_detailed_sqlerrm
      );
      url_resp := 'Http_Server_Error: ' || Utl_Http.get_detailed_sqlerrm;
   /* raised by URL http://otn.oracle.com/xxx */
   WHEN Utl_Http.http_client_error
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
         'Http_Client_Error: ' || Utl_Http.get_detailed_sqlerrm
      );
      url_resp := 'Http_Client_Error: ' || Utl_Http.get_detailed_sqlerrm;
   /* code for all the other defined exceptions you can recover from */
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
      url_resp := SQLERRM;
END;
```

Then to test it

```
begin
  macp_url_get(url_resp => :url_resp,
               'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=55105&sensor=false');
end;
```

(I know that the googleapi will allow xml response, but there are other web APIs that I use regularly that default to JSON)

Comment: What version of Oracle?  12c introduces native JSON types.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Oracle Database Release 12c Release 1 (12.1.0.2) then you can store JSON in the database in a `VARCHAR2`, `CLOB`, or `BLOB` column, and then query it in SQL using *JSON path expressions* (analogous to XPath expressions for XML).

If you have Release 21c then you can store JSON natively, as JSON data type.

You can use SQL functions **`json_value`**, **`json_query`**, and **`json_table`**, and SQL conditions **`json_exists`**, **`is json`**, **`is not json`**, and **`json_textcontains`**, to query the data.

You can define JSON-specific indexes on the data.

Functions `json_query` and `json_table` are analogous to SQL/XML standard functions `XMLQuery` and `XMLTable` for XML. Condition `json_exists` is analogous to `XMLExists` for XML.

If you're not using JSON data type then you need to ensure that the data in a JSON column is in fact valid JSON data, by defining an *`is json` check constraint* on it.

For Release 12c (12.1.0.2), see [*JSON in Oracle Database*](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246). For Release 21c, see [*JSON Developer's Guide*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adjsn/).

(Affiliation: I work at Oracle.  The views I express on this website are my own and do not necessarily reflect the views of Oracle.)

Comment: Do I need to enable any libraries, or are these functions available to all?

Comment: Available to all. These are SQL functions that are part of the database.

Comment: @Lloyd: you need 12.1.0.2, the initial 12c release which was 12.1.0.1 did **not** contain support for JSON

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Right.  As I said in the first sentence of my post: ***If*** *you have...* ***12.1.0.2.*** ;-)

Comment: @drew: I know. This was intended to make **Lloyd** _aware_ of the subtle difference between .0.2 and .0.1

Comment: That sounds great.  I'll have to check with our team to see when we might be upgrading to that version.

Comment: Hi, @Drew any chance that this package could be installed in the 11 g version?

Comment: @Typo: Not that I know of (and I don't think so). But I don't speak for Oracle Support or Oracle Development. You will probably want to ask that question on an Oracle forum etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PL/JSON project https://github.com/pljson/pljson